# how to implement query with extra column that accumulate number of non empty column

Tags: sql, oracle

Assume there is Oracle table with column `empty` below

```
------------------
| empty  | count |
|  true  |   0   |
|  true  |   0   |
|  false |   1   |
|  true  |   0   |
|  false |   2   |
|  true  |   0   |
|  false |   3   |
|  false |   4   |
|  true  |   0   |
|  false |   5   |
| .............  |
------------------
```

the desired query should return the data `empty` column along with a `count` column above which should record the accumulative amount of rows that `empty` column is not null, and result should not affected by `order by` clause

furthermore, how to improve the query to show result as following table result set? basically let the `empty==true` column keep the count from previous `empty==false` column

```
------------------
| empty  | count |
|  true  |   0   |
|  true  |   0   |
|  false |   1   |
|  true  |   1   |
|  false |   2   |
|  true  |   2   |
|  false |   3   |
|  false |   4   |
|  true  |   4   |
|  true  |   4   |
|  true  |   4   |
|  false |   5   |
| .............  |
------------------
```

update the query here for the second question

```
WITH dates_list AS
  (SELECT TO_DATE('01-31-2018','MM-dd-yyyy') + ROWNUM - 1 AS DAY
  FROM dual
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (TO_DATE('03-31-2018','MM-dd-yyyy') - TO_DATE('01-31-2018','MM-dd-yyyy')+1)
  )
select all_date, week_date, count(case when flag is not null then 1 end) 
              over (partition by flag order by week_date) as cnt
from (
SELECT dates1.day as all_date, dates2.day as week_date, case when dates2.day is null then 0 else 1 end as flag
FROM dates_list dates1
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT *
  FROM dates_list
  WHERE TO_CHAR(DAY,'D') NOT IN (7,1)
  ) dates2 ON dates1.day = dates2.day
)
order by all_date;
```

the sample table in this thread is an simple mock from above table, basically I try to have a index of all non-weekend dates but however any weekend dates should keep the previous non weekend index (0 if none)

Comment: (1) Edit your question and provide the results that you want. (2) SQL tables represent *unordered* sets and "cumulative" implies an ordering.  What column has that information? (3) You mention "empty" but none of the values are empty.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff good point I have revise the question. that `empty` column is just a pseudo case because I don't want to create a confusing table with one column with empty fields and no primary key..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second request is simpler than the first. You don't "improve" the solution to the first problem, you write a different (and simpler) query.

Assuming the ordering is by another column `ord` (which may be numeric, or date, or whatever):

```
select empty, 
       count(case empty when 'false' then 1 end) over (order by ord) as cnt
from   .....
```

Comment: sorry I think the solution may not generate desired results. The result here for `empty==true` situation does not keep count from previous record but always the accumulative amount of all rows where `empty==true`

Comment: Update the question with most recent query and explanation too

Answer (score 1):

If you want the "false" column to be enumerated (and the other values to be 0), then you need a column that specifies the ordering.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so you need a column that specifies the ordering.  Let me call that `id`, for convenience:

```
select t.*,
       (case when empty = 'false' then row_number() over (partition by empty order by id)
             else 0
        end) as count
from t;
```

Comment: @Dreamer . . . If you have a new question, you should ask it as a question not in a comment.