# Oracle case when NOT null?

Tags: sql, oracle

I see a lot of queries made for Oracle using `CASE columnX WHEN NULL`

how to design query if

`CASE columnX WHEN NOT NULL` ?

SQL developer throws an error on the query so how to make condition query using CASE... WHEN...?

```
WITH dates_list AS
  (SELECT TO_DATE('02-19-2018','MM-dd-yyyy') + ROWNUM - 1 AS DAY,
    rownum                                                AS row_num
  FROM dual
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (TO_DATE('03-29-2018','MM-dd-yyyy') - TO_DATE('02-19-2018','MM-dd-yyyy')+1)
  )
SELECT dates1.day, dates2.*, count(case dates2.day when null then 1 else 0 end) 
              over (partition by dates2.day order by dates1.day) as cnt
FROM dates_list dates1
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT *
  FROM dates_list
  WHERE TO_CHAR(DAY,'D') NOT IN (7,1)
  ) dates2 ON dates1.day = dates2.day
ORDER BY dates1.day;
```

above query gives error when I change `when null` to `when not null`

Comment: Show us the complete query. **[Edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Clever usage of the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49177351/edit) link in the comment, I LOVE that idea.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the kind reminder, complete query is updated @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: it is a question extended from this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49165191/how-to-implement-query-with-extra-column-that-accumulate-number-of-non-empty-col

Comment: In your example you can just swap the 1 and 0 over; but as `count()` will count any not-null result, that won't make any difference - you're always counting everything anyway. Perhaps you meant `sum()`, in which case swapping them  would work?

Comment: Whoa! You changed the question from one where your error made sense to another one where you SHOULD NOT get that error. `when something IS NOT NULL` in a CASE expression will not throw an error. Note, though, that you are not using the suggestion from the other thread correctly. There was no "then 1 else 0 end" in that suggestion; the `else` part was left out (resulting in NULL, which is not counted - as opposed to 0, which is). You will get the wrong result with this re-write of that solution.

Comment: @AlexPoole - the OP references another thread, where I suggested the use of analytic `COUNT()` - but not like he/she rewrote it. This confusion is why I like to write `count(case when ... then 'z' end) [over ...]` - but people always push back on that too.

Comment: @mathguy - I prefer that over this kind of sum too (if that is the intent).

Comment: @mathguy oh you are right, I shouldn't save that change in the query in the thread that could be confusing to others read this thread. So I changed it back so it should be consistent. I should be more careful for that in SO

Comment: Yes I think I carelessly put the `dates2.day` before `when` condition so that cause the error. Really appreciate all you nice guys involve and made these nice discussion.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't use the CASE sentence in that way with NULL values, because columnX is never "equal" to NULL. You should use instead:

```
CASE WHEN columnX IS NULL THEN
```

or

```
CASE WHEN columnX IS NOT NULL THEN
```

Comment: To add to Alex's answer: The CASE expression has two forms, the "simple" CASE expression and the "searched" CASE expression. In a "simple" CASE expression you compare one expression to one or more values; that doesn't work with NULL, as we know from the first week of SQL classes. The "searched" CASE expression evaluates much more general logical "conditions", not just equality. This (and the slightly different syntax) is what Alex demonstrates in this Answer.

Answer (score 1):

You now have a function NVL that can turn this:

```
CASE WHEN columnX IS NOT NULL THEN columnX ELSE 'No value' END
```

Into this:

```
NVL(columnX, 'No value')
```

If columnX is a select, it make everything a lot cleaner